# Font issue with Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I just updated Google Chrome to version 34 and got this:

[image: Ignore the "Close"]

As you can see, the tab title font uses these narrow letters, whereas other texts are as they were before the update.

Does any one of you know where this comes from and how to fix it?

I'm using Kubuntu Raring x64 (Yes, I know its EOL, but I damaged the system so much a release upgrade would totally break it. I'm soon getting a new device and I want to keep a running system until then...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed in newer versions of Chrome (at least for me.)